# how to print entire HTML page in angular4

Tags: angular

I want to print entire page in Angular 4 and I am using the below code for the same. But I have to write CSS separately.

```
    _PrintReceipt = async () => {  
    let printContents, popupWin;  
    printContents = document.getElementById('print-section').innerHTML;  
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');  
    popupWin.document.open();  
    popupWin.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Receipt</title>
          <style>
            .print-section {
              margin: 2%;
            }
            ...........
          </style>
        </head>
        <body onload="window.print();window.close()"><div class="print- 
              section">${printContents}</div></body>
      </html>`
    );  
    popupWin.document.close();
  }
```

**Is there a way to print the html page as it is?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript `window.print()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print)